# convert a html table to a 2D array with numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I use the below JavaScript function to generate a html table from a 2D data array with numbers called d.

```
function matrix(d) {
var html = '<table>';
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
html += '<tr>';
for (var j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++) {
  html += '<td>' + d[i][j] + '</td>';
    }
html += "</tr>";
  }
return html;
}
```

That function works well but I can only look at the pretty html output and not use the data in other functions so now I am trying to write another function that goes in the opposite direction and converts a html table to a 2D array with numbers. So far I got the below function:

```
function tableToArray(w) {
var myTableArray = [];
$(w).each(function() { 
var arrayOfThisRow = [];
var tableData = $(this).find('td');
if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
     }
    });
  console.log(myTableArray); 
  return myTableArray; 
  }
```

but that function is not working very well. If I call tableToArray(matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])) the result in the console.log is a 1D column array with strings (or maybe a 1D row array with string hard to tell the difference in the console log) that looks like "1","2","3","4","5","6". I want a 2D array with numbers and not strings since my original array was a 2D array with numbers. What JavaScript function code will give me that 2D array with numbers?

Assigning the data array d to a global variable (without var) or a window.variable is not an option because I need to be able to call the function likes this: tableToArray(matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])).

I have googled around all day to find a previous written function that does this but I have not managed to find a working one nor have I been successful in writing one myself.

Comment: JS is not PHP; don't concatenate strings. Instead, directly build the DOM elements you need using `document.createElement`, and if their content is text/numerical, use `element.textContent = ...` and if it's other DOM elements, use `element.appendChild(thatChildElement)`, then return the `table` element you built in that way for whatever needs to insert the table into the document, and have that also `appendChild` it to whatever its parent element is supposed to be.

Comment: The problem is not generating a html table with JavaScript. I can generate it the way you want me to. I have already successfully done that. The problem is going back the other way and getting the original data array. appendChild will not work for my application because I have a complex parser function that does that work.

Comment: But that makes zero sense: your `matrix` function shows it takes the original data array for turning it into HTML. So if "building the HTML" is not the problem, you already have the data you're asking about? It's whatever you're calling `matrix()` with.